# About Euclidean distances

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Let $0<d_1<\cdots<d_k<\infty$ and let $m_1,\dots,m_k$ be any integers $\ge1$. Let $n:=m_1+\dots+m_k-1$.
Let $d$ denote the Euclidean distance in $\R^n$.

> Do then there always exist pairwise disjoint subsets $S_1,\dots,S_k$ of $\R^n$ of respective cardinalities $m_1,\dots,m_k$ such that
> $$d(x,y)=d_j$$
> for all $j\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ and all $(x,y)\in T_j\times S_j$ with $x\ne y$, where $T_j:=S_1\cup\dots\cup S_j$?

This conjecture is obviously true for $k=1$ and seems not hard to prove for $k=2$.

---

Reviewing the edits suggested by MattF., one can restate the conjecture in the following way:

> Let $n$ be any natural number. Suppose that $0<d_1\le\cdots\le d_{n+1}<\infty$.

> Do then there always exist pairwise distinct points $x_1,\dots,x_{n+1}$ in $\R^n$ such that
> $$d(x_i,x_j)=d_j$$
> for all integers $i,j$ such that $1\le i<j\le n+1$?

Comment: Is there some heuristic that suggests that such arrangements should exist?

Comment: @LSpice : I have added a sentence in support of this conjecture.

Comment: I gave an informative title which I think is equivalent to the stated question, since a distance $d$ of cardinality $m$ is equivalent to $m$ repetitions of $d$ in the list of distances, and the requirement of points in dimension $n$ is equivalent to a requirement of some linear dependence.

Comment: @MaytF: On thelast issue, any $n+1$ points lie in an $n$-dim affine sibspace.

Comment: @MattF. : The edits you made resulted in something I think not equivalent to the original question. So, I reversed the edits. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finite [ultrametric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space) [allow isometric embeddings into $L_2$](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82490074.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

**[Trying to rewrite everything]**

**Lemma 1** The altitude of a regular simplex of side $a$ is larger than $a/\sqrt2$.

*Proof* Folllows from the fact that the central angle of every edge of a regular simplex is obtuse.

**Lemma 2** Let $P$ be either (i) $\mathbb R^n$, or (ii) an $n$-dim sphere (in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$). Then there exist $n+2$ points in $P$ such that
$$
  \text{all their pairwise distances equal $a$, except for one which is at least $a$} 
  \qquad (*)
$$
iff either (i) holds, or (ii) holds, with the sidelength of the inscribed $(n+2)$-vertex simplex being at least $a$.

*Proof* If $P$ does not contain $n+1$ points forming a regular simplex of side length $a$, then both conditions are violated.

Otherwise, consider such simplex. Let $O$ be the center of the sphere, $M$ be the center of the simplex, and $N$ be the centerr of one of its facets, $A$ being the complementary vertex of the simplex. When the radius of the sphere grows, $OM$ grows as well, while $OM\perp MN$ always.

If (i) holds, then $n+2$ points are obtained by reflecting the vertex in the corresponding facet, and by Lemma 1 we are done. Assume (ii). To get the $(n+2)$th point $A'$ on $P$ equidistant from the facet's vertices, we need to reflex $A$ in $ON$; since $\angle ONM$ is growing, the distance $AA'$ is increasing, wo $AA'\geq a$ iff the sphere is large enough in order to fit the regular simplex with side $a$.

$$ $$

Now, ket $P$ be as in Lemma 2, satisfying $(*)$ with $a=d_k$. We claim that the required sets $S_1,\dots, S_k$ can be found on $P$.

Induction on $k$. The base case $k=1$ is provided by Lemma 2.

For the step, choose a set $S$ of $n+2$ points on $P$ satisfying $(*)$ with $a=d_k$. Then $m_k$ of them go to the set $S_k$. Other sets to be constructed should lie on $P$, as well as on the $(n-m_k+1)$-dimensional sphere cpnsisting of points at distance $d_k$ from all points of $S_k$. The intersection of those spheres is an $(n-m_k)$-dimensional sphere containing $n-m_k+2$ points (from $S$) satisfying $(*)$ with $a=d_k$, so a fortiori with $a=d_{k-1}$; hence we can apply the inductive hypothesis to this sphere getting the other desired sets.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand about any part of your answer, including the following: (i) You seem to imply that the considerations on $P$ imply the result for $\mathbb R^n$. If so, why? (ii) Why "'equivalent to" in your second sentence? (iii) What exactly is your statement $(*)$? (iv) What is your inductive step? (v) Why do you **choose** $n+2$ poinrts for such a **step** -- if we have to **end up** with $n+1$ points? (vi) Why is the set "cpnsisting of points at distance $d_k$ from all points of $S_k$" a sphere? Etc., etc.

Comment: Previous comment continued: Can you please present a formal proof, with all terms defined, using otherwise just terms like "because", "hence", "and", "or", "not"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis any $n+1$ points in Euclidean space of any dimension are actually in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @IosifPinelis I hope it is more comprehendible now; I've added many details.

Comment: Sorry again. I cannot parse your Lemma 2. It seems to contain a statement of the form $A\iff B$. What exactly are $A$ and $B$ here? In particular, conditions (i) and (ii) seem to be both in the preamble to the statement $A\iff B$ and in $B$. Also, what is "the inscribed $(n+2)$-vertex simplex"?

Comment: @FedorPetrov : Of course, I agree with the content of your comment. But what is its point in this context?

Comment: @IosifPinelis you are looking for $n+1$ points, right? Then if we find them on any sphere of any dimension, they are found in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : As I said, I understood nothing in the previous version of the answer (and I still do not understand most of the latter version). In particular, I did not (and still do not) know what metric was used on the sphere -- I guessed it would be the geodesic one, and so it was unclear to me how that would translate into Euclidean distances in $\mathbb R^n$.